# How to solve the Network request failed error in react-native with expo?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, fetch, expo

I'm trying to fetch information from my local API with React-native and expo using the fetch method.

```js
export function getBoardGamesFromApiWithSearchedText (text) {
    const url = 'http://localhost:2021/boardgame/list'

    return fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
}
```

I have this error **:**

> Network request failed at
> node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:535:17 in
> setTimeout$argument_0

I saw that many people had this problem, apparently solved with the following solution:
https://jsshowcase.com/question/react-native-fetch-https-localhost-network-request-failed

But I can't find the info.plist file maybe in the app.json but what should I configure?

I'm new to react native. Can someone help me on this ?